# JBoss Negotiation in Jboss AS 7.1.1. Error testing toolkit through AD

Tags: active-directory, jboss7.x, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

I'm testing the jboss negotiation toolkit and can successfully accomplish only the first two steps "Basic Negotiation" and "Security Domain Test". The last step, "Secured" presents the "Unable to authenticate: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Specified version of key is not available (44))" error. I google it but i couldn't find something usefull, i generated the "SecureKey" again and the error remains the same

---

**1 Generated SecureKey**:

```
Z:\>ktpass -princ mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@domain.com -out C:\usuarioAD.mttsrvdc01.keytab -pass 1234 -mapuser krypton\usuarioAD -crypto RC4-HMAC-NT -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
Targeting domain controller: mttsrvdc01.domain.com
Using legacy password setting method
WARNING: realm "domain.com" has lowercase characters in it.
         We only currently support realms in UPPERCASE.
         assuming you mean "DOMAIN.COM"...
Successfully mapped mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD to usuarioAD.
Key created.
Output keytab to C:\usuarioAD.mttsrvdc01.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 83 mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@domain.com ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRI
NCIPAL) vno 6 etype 0x17 (RC4-HMAC) keylength 16 (0x13c61e319351b92678bef514728d
011b)

Z:\>setspn.exe -l usuarioAD
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for [XYZ]:
    mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD
```

**2 Standalone.xml (JBOSS 7.1.1)**

```
<security-domain name="host" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Kerberos" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="principal" value="mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@DOMAIN.COM"/>
                            <module-option name="keyTab" value="C:\usuarioAD.mttsrvdc01.keytab"/>
                            <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="requisite">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="AdvancedAdLdap" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            <module-option name="bindAuthentication" value="GSSAPI"/>
                            <module-option name="jaasSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://mttsrvdc01:389"/>
                            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="OU=MTT,DC=USERS,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com,DC=br"/>
                            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(userPrincipalName={0})"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
                            <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                            <module-option name="recurseRoles" value="true"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

**3 First and second test in toolkit**

```
NEGOTIATION TOOLKIT
•   Basic Negotiation
WWW-Authenticate - Negotiate YHkGBisGAQUFAqBvMG2gMDAuBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHqI5BDdOVExNU1NQAAEAAACXsgjiBwAHADAAAAAIAAgAKAAAAAYBsR0AAAAPTVRUREVWNTVLUllQVE9O
•   NegTokenInit
Message Oid - SPNEGO
Mech Types - {NTLM} {Kerberos V5 Legacy} {Kerberos V5} {1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30}
Req Flags -
Mech Token -TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl7II4gcABwAwAAAACAAIACgAAAAGAbEdAAAAD01UVERFVjU1S1JZUFRPTg==
Mech List Mic -


NEGOTIATION TOOLKIT
•   Security Domain Test
Testing security-domain 'host'
Authenticated
Assunto:
Principal: mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@DOMAIN.COM
Credencial Privada: Ticket (hex) = 
0000: 61 82 01 35 30 82 01 31 A0 03 02 01 05 A1 19 1B a..50..1........
0010: 17 4B 52 59 50 54 4F 4E 2E 4D 45 54 41 54 52 4F .DOMAIN.........
0020: 4E 2E 43 4F 4D 2E 42 52 A2 2C 30 2A A0 03 02 01 .COM.BR.,0*.....
0030: 02 A1 23 30 21 1B 06 6B 72 62 74 67 74 1B 17 4B ..#0!..krbtgt..D
0040: 52 59 50 54 4F 4E 2E 4D 45 54 41 54 52 4F 4E 2E OMAIN.COM.......
0050: 43 4F 4D 2E 42 52 A3 81 E0 30 81 DD A0 03 02 01 COM.BR...0......
0060: 17 A1 03 02 01 02 A2 81 D0 04 81 CD 91 C5 8C 7A ...............z
0070: 6E F7 2A 44 33 62 43 CB 96 E1 F2 BC 39 B9 C8 92 n.*D3bC.....9...
0080: DB BA 0E D5 5D FA B4 E4 AA 08 13 D2 7E 2F BE 02 ....]......../..
0090: 43 FC 02 86 C7 BE F6 D6 58 B6 6A 3B A3 B7 F2 1C C.......X.j;....
00A0: 15 33 9A C0 20 BB 4D 77 E0 95 17 26 73 0C CA 5C .3.. .Mw...&s..\
00B0: B7 A5 47 DC 5A 49 25 D6 4F 52 79 1D 74 BC E3 BD ..G.ZI%.ORy.t...
00C0: 8C A8 A0 0B 05 74 F3 61 B7 6C 17 29 DC D1 F6 0B .....t.a.l.)....
00D0: 03 15 16 08 D7 22 5F 8A BC 5B E2 A3 48 58 7B 01 ....."_..[..HX..
00E0: CA 67 27 DF 5C 0C D1 E2 19 67 A7 EC D3 70 CD 94 .g'.\....g...p..
00F0: 97 BE 47 B4 F8 2E 50 5C E0 F7 21 3A 17 D7 F0 25 ..G...P\..!:...%
0100: D7 0F B0 23 F2 E4 94 2C CF E0 D5 5F B2 CA 1E 5B ...#...,..._...[
0110: C0 0D 83 57 70 C8 43 FF 90 F9 33 1F 96 ED A5 99 ...Wp.C...3.....
0120: F1 7F C9 D1 9B 28 C6 50 42 6C 36 F5 4C 41 35 19 .....(.PBl6.LA5.
0130: 7E 73 7A 26 56 71 20 8D 79 .sz&Vq .y

Client Principal = mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@DOMAIN.COM
Server Principal = krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM
Session Key = EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: 60 46 45 1C F8 FD 44 26 50 B7 40 42 F1 06 A3 2E `FE...D&P.@B....


Forwardable Ticket false
Forwarded Ticket false
Proxiable Ticket false
Proxy Ticket false
Postdated Ticket false
Renewable Ticket false
Initial Ticket false
Auth Time = Thu Sep 04 15:46:17 BRT 2014
Start Time = Thu Sep 04 15:46:17 BRT 2014
End Time = Fri Sep 05 01:46:17 BRT 2014
Renew Till = null
Client Addresses Null 
Credencial Privada: C:\usuarioAD.mttsrvdc01.keytab
Credencial Privada: Kerberos Principal mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@DOMAIN.COMKey Version 6key EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: 13 C6 1E 31 93 51 B9 26 78 BE F5 14 72 8D 01 1B ...1.Q.&x...r...
```

**4 Stacktrace**

```
15:46:35,722 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is C:\usuarioAD.mttsrvdc01.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@DOMAIN.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
15:46:35,733 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) principal is mttsrvdc01/usuarioAD@DOMAIN.COM

15:46:35,734 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) Will use keytab

15:46:35,736 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) Commit Succeeded 
15:46:35,737 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) 

15:46:35,759 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1)      [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout

15:46:35,760 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1)      [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject

15:46:35,761 ERROR [org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) Unable to authenticate: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Specified version of key is not available (44))
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:788) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule$AcceptSecContext.run(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:396) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.spnegoLogin(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:237) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.innerLogin(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:194) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.login(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:137) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator.authenticate(NegotiationAuthenticator.java:187) [jboss-negotiation-common-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:455) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: KrbException: Specified version of key is not available (44)
    at sun.security.krb5.EncryptionKey.findKey(EncryptionKey.java:588) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:144) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    ... 35 more

15:46:35,827 ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to authenticate - Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Specified version of key is not available (44))
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.login(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:163) [jboss-negotiation-spnego-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.7.Final.jar:4.0.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:214) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator.authenticate(NegotiationAuthenticator.java:187) [jboss-negotiation-common-2.2.0.SP1.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:455) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
```

Comment: Is the test platform still up and running?  Before answering, I wanted to make sure any answer given can be verified against the original problem architecture.

Answer (score 0):

"Specified version of key is not available (44)"

IIRC "version" is a sequence number of service account password resets, and your keytab must have it match the real one. Also the password must match, and you might want to add other encoded forms than hmac-rc4 (AES256 maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

Try set kvno of you keytab = 0

Using jdk ktab you can use parameter -n to do it

I use this key types:

default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
When I try with aes128-cts I received a checksum error.